# Adding a space between next and previous post links

Tags: theme-development, next-post-link

i've been struggling with this for a while but i can't seem to make it work.So i wanna add a space between my next and pervious post link right now it looks like this : [image]

Here's a pastebin of my template-tags.php : http://pastebin.com/8htBKgYm
Any ideas ? 
Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could for example change

`<?php next_post_link ( '%link &rarr;', '%title', true, '', 'category' ); ?>`

to `<?php next_post_link ( '<div style="float: right">%link &rarr;</div>', '%title', true, '', 'category' ); ?>`